# Plugging domain controller into another network

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, dhcp, wifi, domain-controller

I have a W2K8 domain controller network and everything was working perfectly on a network router on 192.168.0.1. It is also a DHCP server.

I had to temporarily move the domain controller into another physical place. So I plugged it into a router that is in charge of 192.168.1.1. How do I make both networks work in parallel? I want some laptops to connect wirelessly to the 192.168.1.1 router, but get on the 192.168.0.1 like they were on before, so they have access to the shared files.

How can I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

two nics on the domain controller. each nic for each subnet. each nic goes into a 1 port of a managed switch (like hp procurve or something), create two vlans (vlan 1 = subnet 1) (vlan 2= subnet 2)

packets don't collide the managed switch takes cares of routes.
gd

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have the two routers on separate network segments? You could make the router for the 192.168.1.1 subnet operate in switch mode and forward dhcp data from the W2K8 server. Note this would effectively collapse your 2 subnets into one.

Another way you could provide access to shared files is to forward the Netbios ports from the server at its 192.168.1.x address to an address in the 192.168.0.1 subnet, potentially even the address it formerly occupied.

It's hard to answer your question without knowing a little more about your needs. What is the network topology - for example why do you have two routers? What are your security requirements if any? What services does the domain controller provide and on what ports?